# Aumentar entero a objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando con objetos y tengo este método `curarPersonas` donde se supone debe de sumar uno a la variable `personasCuradas` cada vez que entra a la función; pero solo lo suma una vez y en la segunda ni siquiera la muestra. Me pregunto si hay alguna forma de incrementar dicho valor.

```
function medicoInternas(nombreDoctor, personasCuradas, especialidadDoctor) {
    this.nombre = nombreDoctor;
    this.curadas = personasCuradas;
    this.especialidad = especialidadDoctor;

    this.curarPersona = function() {

        this.curadas = parseInt(this.curadas);
        this.curadas++;
        alert("Persona curada, total de personas curadas " + this.curadas);
    }

    this.mostrarDatos = function() {
        window.alert("El nombre del medico es: " + this.nombre + " su especialidad es: " + this.especialidad + " y lleva " + this.curadas + " personas curadas");
    }
}

function arranca(valor) {

  var medico = new medicoInternas(aquiVaUnNombre", 0, "AquiUnaEsp");

  if (valor == "curar"){
      medico.curarPersona();
    }
  else {
        medico.mostrarDatos();
    }   
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que llamas a `arrancar` **se está creando una nueva instancia de** `medicoInternas`, por lo que, si se llama a `curarPersonas` **aumentará de 0 a 1** y cuando termine la ejecución de `arrancar` **el objeto** `medico` **será destruído**.

Debes instanciar a `medicoInternas` **fuera de la función** `arrancar`:

```
var medico = new MedicoInternas("Leslie", 0, "Cardiología");

function arrancar (valor) {
  if (valor === 'curar') {
    medico.curarPersonas();
  } else {
    medico.mostrarDatos();
  }
}
```

> Es mejor añadir los métodos de instancia **en el prototipo** de la función

Toda función en JavaScript tiene un objeto especial, llamado `prototype` que hereda de `Object`. En este objeto especial están **todas las propiedades y funciones** que tendrá toda instancia de dicha función.

Agregar las funciones en el prototipo de una función base significa ganar rendimiento y buenas prácticas. Cuando creas funciones vía `this` estás haciendo **que se cree una nueva función por cada instancia** de la función base; esto es muy malo ya que degrada mucho el rendimiento en aplicaciones complejas. Lo correcto es agregar funciones al prototipo:

```
function MedicoInternas (data) {
  this.nombre = data.nombre;
  this.curadas = data.personasCuradas;
  this.especialidad = data.especialidadDoctor;
}

MedicoInternas.prototype.curarPersona = function () {
  this.curadas++;
  console.info('Persona curada');
};

MedicoInternas.prototype.mostrarDatos = function () {
  console.info('Nombre:', this.nombre);
  console.info('Personas curadas:', this.personasCuradas);
  console.info('Especialidad:', this.especialidad);
}
```

De esta manera **cada instancia de** `MedicoInternas` **compartirán las mismas funciones**. Esto es lo correcto y lo óptimo y debe hacerse así.

**Código final**

```js
function MedicoInternas (data) {
  this.nombre = data.nombre;
  this.curadas = data.personasCuradas;
  this.especialidad = data.especialidad;
}

MedicoInternas.prototype.curarPersona = function () {
  this.curadas++;
  console.info('Persona curada');
};

MedicoInternas.prototype.mostrarDatos = function () {
  console.info('Nombre:', this.nombre);
  console.info('Personas curadas:', this.curadas);
  console.info('Especialidad:', this.especialidad);
}

let medico = new MedicoInternas({
  nombre: 'Leslie',
  personasCuradas: 0,
  especialidad: 'Cardiología'
});

arrancar('curar');
arrancar('curar');
arrancar('curar');
console.log('\n');
arrancar('datos');

function arrancar (action) {
  if (action === 'curar') {
    medico.curarPersona();
  } else {
    medico.mostrarDatos();
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, debí de suponerlo ya que tampoco aumentaba en la segunda ya que entra y sale de la función jeje.

Espero pronto poder comenzar con prototype ya que se ve mucho mas funcional.

Comment: JavaScript implementa la POO diferente a otros lenguajes como Java, C# o Python. Si vienes de allí **olvídate de dicha POO mientras estudias JavaScript** porque te confundirá. La POO que implementa JavaScript se llama *"orientada a prototipos"*. Te recomiendo leas los libros: JavaScript, the good parts y Eloquent JavaScript.

Comment: Si, de echo vengo de Java y me impresiono que en tu código solo pusieses un argumento referenciando un objeto en lugar de tres como lo hice yo y se hace en Java jajja, buscare los libros, gracias por la info!

Comment: En javascript ya se puede hacer uso de POO de una forma mucho mas parecida a Java, clases, herencia etc.

https://medium.com/ecmascript-2015/es6-classes-and-inheritance-607804080906

Comment: @JesúsPerales Lo único parecido que se tiene es la sintaxis, nada más. La keyword `class` de ES6 te permite creando **funciones constructoras** de una manera más "concisa" a como se hace en lenguajes como Java o C#; detrás de escenas **nada cambia**, siguen siendo funciones con prototipo.

Comment: Si, pero ese es tema de otro debate. 
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-s-the-difference-between-class-prototypal-inheritance-e4cd0a7562e9